# Not sure how to optimize active record association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, data-access

I have a piece of code that gets an associated object by id, otherwise it initializes a new object.

```
def pick_for_game(game_id)
   picks.find_or_initialize_by_game_id(game_id)
end
```

The picks collection will typically have several hundred items in it. The two use cases are:

1. I want to call this method for 15-30 games
2. I want to call this method for all games

Seems like the current approach is ok for use case a, but is absolutely terrible for use case b. I could make this method complicated based on whether or not picks has been eagerly loaded like the following:

```
def pick_for_game(game_id)
  if picks.loaded?
    new_pick = proc {
      Pick.new do |p|
        p.game_id = game_id
      end
    }
    picks.detect(new_pick) do |p|
      p.game_id == game_id
    end
  else
    picks.find_or_initialize_by_game_id(game_id)
  end
end
```

However, would picking one approach over the other for all cases have any merit other than making the code a little cleaner? Any other solutions to this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming Pick is a model, if you know the list of game_ids you can fetch all existing Picks for the specified Games in one query and only initialize new Picks for the remaining game_ids:

```
def picks_for_games( game_ids )
  existing_picks = Pick.all( :conditions => { :game_id => game_ids } )
  game_ids_without_picks = game_ids - existing_picks.map{ |x| x.game_id }
  new_picks = game_ids_without_picks.map { 
                |game_id| Pick.initialize_by_game_id( game_id ) 
              }
  return picks + new_picks
end
```

You could switch between the 2 implementations depending on:

```
if game_ids.is_a?( Array )
```

An option for b) would be to add an association on Game for any Picks that reference it so then you can quickly query for games that have no pick(s) and initialize a pick for each.

```
Game.all( :conditions => { :picks => nil } ).map { |game| Pick.initialize_by_game_id( game.id ) }
```